# how to solve this android studio button error?

Tags: android-studio

```
<Button
    android:onClick="login"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="296dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="524dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    android:text="@string/nothing"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="-" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

```
public void login(View view) {
    Intent in = new Intent(this,loginActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

i run the app and try to clcick on the button, button show up in device but i can't click it

how to solve this error?